# How to handle choppy drawing as Views are being added to a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 10 views that are being added to a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation. This all occurs at runtime. However, each time the layout is redrawn, the user can see the choppy transition from a blank layout to one with all 10 views added. What's the recommended approach to reduce the choppiness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you must be using some custom View that does a lot of processing during onDraw(). Try doing all the processing you can in advance or in a separate thread.

Also, using a ListView as inazaruk proposes will let you separate data generation from View rendering.

If that is not the case, look in your code if you are creating several objects in onDraw(). If so, reformat your code so you reuse those objects. That will prevent the garbage collector for kicking in all the time to recover your unused memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all 10 items before `LinearLayout` is rendered (for example in `onCreate` method).

Or you can use `ListView` instead. You can find more details in [ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

Comment: +1 a ListView is probably the way to go, but if it's choppy in every draw as opposed to when being added only, I guess there is more than one problem in that code.

Comment: Yes, it looks like your are right. Its just 10 views, re-rendering shouldn't be noticeable unless `onDraw` is complex enough.